# How to move/migrate old notes to new Notes?

Tags: data-loader, notes, contentnote

With the new Notes, my users complain that they want all of their old notes in the new format.
Knowing dataloader, I am trying to export all of the old notes and insert as new Notes, but I can't find the note (old) object in the scheme, or how to insert to the Notes.

- Schema builder shows me nothing of Notes, or the old note
- I looked at the [NoteAndAttachment](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_noteandattachment.htm) object (I think all the old notes are there), but this item can't be queried

[image]

- I believe [ContentNote](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentnote.htm) is the new Note object, so an insert with dataloader is easy. And to attach to the correct object is through AttachedContent - but this object is **read only**, so how?

  1. How do I export all the old notes and their relations?
  2. How do I insert the old data as new Notes to the correct related parent object?

Comment: I guess schema builder runs on older version or API .Try to query in workbench and see if it works.

Comment: I've put together code for converting Notes > ContentNotes and Attachments > ContentVersions you might find helpful: https://douglascayers.com/2015/10/10/salesforce-convert-attachments-to-chatter-files/

Answer (score 2):

To help folks migrate from Classic Notes (Note) to Enhanced Notes (ContentNote) I've developed open source project on GitHub:

https://github.com/DouglasCAyers/sfdc-convert-notes-to-chatter-notes

And if you're converting notes you might also want to convert Classic Attachments (Attachment) to Salesforce Files (ContentVersion):

https://github.com/DouglasCAyers/sfdc-convert-attachments-to-chatter-files

The conversion is done entirely in Apex and handles sharing via ContentDocumentLink the new note/file (ContentNote/ContentVersion) with the original parent record.

Comment: Hey Doug ! thanks for this awesome tool - i just tried and it works for handful of records. I is failing however for 4000 that I tried - with the: First error: Too many SOQL queries: 201  error in the batch apex job status. Can you help us with that?

Answer (score 0):

Data loader can export all your old notes. I used Note as object.
Reuse the parent Id.

The import csv cannot contain the note body in the csv. It's kind of like uploading attachments.

> Because ContentNote is based on Salesforce CRM Content functionality,
>   the Content column must contain a path to a local file. The body of
>   the note may not be contained within the CSV file.

[Salesforce on importing to new Notes, aka, ContentNote](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Importing-Notes-to-the-ContentNote-object-using-the-Apex-Data-Loader&language=en_US)

Other info with an import tool ...

[importing Notes etc](http://www.ktema.org//2016/08/24/importing-notes-into-salesforce/)